# массив в результате sql

Tags: sql, join

Как можно сохранить выборку, которая происходит в `JOIN`, в отдельный подмассив. Есть такой запрос, он выбирает сообщения и прикрепленные файлы к ним(связка через таблицу `ticket_attachment`):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ost3_ticket_thread` th 
LEFT JOIN `ost3_ticket_attachment` at ON (th.id=at.ref_id) 
LEFT JOIN `ost3_file` fl ON (at.file_id=fl.id) 
WHERE th.`ticket_id` = 266
```

но у 1го сообщения сразу 3 вложения, соответственно создаются 3 записи одного и того же сообщения с разными вложениями.

получаю структуру(логическое представление):

```
mess1 
- attach1
mess2 
- attach2
mess2 
- attach3
mess3 
- attach4
```

а хочу получить(логическое представление):

```
   mess1 
    - attach1
   mess2 
    - attach2
    - attach3
   mess3 
    - attach4
```

какие конструкции языка на это способны?

Comment: SQL возвращает строго таблицу, а не структуру. у таблицы 2 измерения строки и столбцы. других вариантов нет. если вам нужно уложить эти данные в структуры то делайте это на стороне клиента читая построчно и формируя структуру. Со стороны SQL можно данные сгруппировать и для группы значения какого то из полей собрать в строку, например через запятую. Но в стандартах SQL таких функций нет. они есть только в конкретных СУБД у каждой свои

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case when rowno=1 then messname else '' end  messname, attachname from 
(
select mess.name messname, 
 attach.name attachname, 
 row_number() over (partition by mess.id order by attach.id) rowno 
 from mess 
 left join attach on attach.messid=mess.id) a
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb3c9/8

Имя сообщения будет заполнено только в первой записи к этому сообщению. Но записей по прежнему будет две.

Если же Вы хотите получить некий объект, имеющий больше чем два измерения - это несколько выходит за рамки SQL.

Comment: А как вы поняли, что можно использовать оконные функции. ТС же не указал СУБД. Да и про подавление значений вроде речи вообще не шло ...

Comment: MS, Oracle, Postgres - умеют. В стандарте есть. Замена в MySql гуглится примерно за 30 секунд.

Comment: а чисто теоретически, можно формировать строку вместо массива? например что бы получилось вот так:
mess1 
- attach1
||
mess2 
- attach2,attach3
||
mess3 
- attach4

Comment: @Maximmka, склеить несколько строк в одну? Можно, но тогда лучше всё-таки указать диалект. И это будет не массив, это будет несколько строк, склеенных в одну.

Comment: спасибо за рассуждения, было познавательно. сделаю всё таки несколько запросов, понятнее будет, ради тех кто придёт после меня.

Comment: @Maximmka никогда не делайте несколько запросов. те кто придут после вас будут очень долго матерится, когда система будет безбожно тормозить уже на сотне записей. Лучше бы в вопросе указали какой язык используете и какую структуру хотите получить. например в php PDO умеет сам собирать подобные структуры (с ограничениями). В других случаях получаете отсортированные по mess данные и в цикле чтения проверяете предыдущее значение этого поля, если поменялось, значит заводим новую структуру, если нет - добавляем в старую

Comment: использую php pdo. про пробег по массиву с 3мя одинаковыми mess не задумался, хотя это вполне реально, был увлечён идеей получить всё прямо из sql. спасибо за наставление, так и сделаю